# Using scalar valued function in MSSM with data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, unpivot

I would like to here your advice on using a scalar valued function on MSSM that calculate average of data set coming 2 different table.

each table consist 12 columns that represent the values, in addition each table have 3 more columns to differ the data and when calculating the average these 3 columns should match (Product_ID, SalesRep_ID, and date (year)) on both tables

I Tried scalar valued function like this:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Sales_BU_ScenarioB_PriceAv](@Product_ID nvarchar(255), @SalesRep_ID float, @Year float) 
    RETURNS decimal(18,0)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result decimal(18,0)

    set @Result =  (SELECT 
    case when
    (
     isnull(q.P01,0) 
     + isnull(q.P02,0) 
     + isnull(q.P03,0) 
    ... 
     + isnull(q.P12,0)
     )
     =0
    then
    0
    else
    (isnull(p.P01,0)*isnull(q.P01,0)
     + isnull(p.P02,0)*isnull(q.P02,0) 
     + isnull(p.P03,0)*isnull(q.P03,0)
     ...
     + isnull(p.P12,0)*isnull(q.P12,0)
     )
     /
     (
     isnull(q.P01,0) 
     + isnull(q.P02,0) 
     + isnull(q.P03,0) 
    ... 
     + isnull(q.P12,0)
     )
     end
     from DataEntrySalesQty$ q, DataEntrySalesPrice$ p
     where  @Year = p.Year and
            @Product_ID = p.Product_ID and
            @SalesRep_ID = p.SalesRep_ID) 
        RETURN @Result
   END
```

this should calculate: sum((p.P01 * q.P01)....(p.P12 * q.P12)) and divide by: sum(q.P01,q.P02....q.P12) in order to get the average price for all relevant rows in these columns.

it looks like the function works when I run it, but when trying to test the result

```
select
Product_ID, SalesRep_ID, [Year], [dbo].[Sales_BU_ScenarioB_PriceAv](Product_ID, SalesRep_ID, [Year])
from DataEntrySalesQty$
```

I get the next error:
**Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

can you please help me understand what i am doing wrong?

thanks for all the helpers

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using old-style joins via the where clause. And did you notice the join error? That would be obvious using the join syntx.

Comment: @SMor how can I use join syntax in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `cross apply` to unpivot the columns to rows, then aggregation:

```
select 
    q.product_id,
    q.year,
    q.salesrep_id,
    sum(x.p * x.q) / sum(x.q) avg_price
from DataEntrySalesPrice$ AS p
inner join DataEntrySalesQty$ AS q
    on  q.product_id = p.product_id 
    and q.year = p.year 
    and q.salesrep_id = p.salesrep_id
cross apply (values 
    (p.p01, q.q01), 
    (p.p02, q.q02), 
    ..., 
    (p.p12, q.q12)
) as x(p, q)
group by q.product_id, q.year,  q.salesrep_id
```

Comment: thanks @GMB for the quick replay! I would like to use this functionality on scalar valued function as it is a repeated calculation i would use, is it possible ?